# Is there a way to order an associative array by how the keys are inserted with PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

Here's an example of what I mean:

I have an array:

```
array('type'=>'text', 
      'class'=>'input', 
      'name'=>'username', 
      'id'=>'username', 
      'value'=>'', 
      'size'=>'30', 
      'rows'=>'',
    'cols'=>'');
```

Then, I loop through it like so:

```
$input = '<input ';
    foreach($input_array as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($key) && !empty($key)) {
            $input .= $key . '="' . $value . '" ';
        }   
    }   
$input .= '/>';
```

I'm hoping to return:

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="username" id="username" size="30" />
```

I've tried using PHP's sort() functions to no avail.  The nearest I can figure is I'd need to use something like usort(), but I'm having trouble figuring how to write a function which will do what I want.

Any advice on this topic is greatly appreciated, and thanks very much for reading.

Comment: What order do you get if you don't sort it?

Comment: As Mr. Haigh pointed out, (once I had all my ducks in a row), it output the way I had set it, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should already be in that order. PHP arrays are sorted so the elements will be in the order in which you inserted them.

You also need to call `empty()` on `$value` not `$key`; `$key` should always be non-empty. You also don't need `isset()` as well as `empty()`. Apart from that your code works fine and produces the desired output.

I would also be wary of using `empty()` because it will return true for a string '0'. This could be a valid parameter value which would be ignored. You could instead check that `strlen($value) > 0`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I had originally supposed that would be the case.  However, using the above code, my html output is:

<input type="text" cols="" rows="" size="30" value="" id="username" name="username" class="input"/>

Which suggests that my isset() / !empty() combination is incorrect, and also that, for some reason, my order is also incorrect. However, when I print_r() the array, it shows up in the correct order as it should.  How can I continue to troubleshoot this?

Much thanks for a quick response!

Comment: I apologize, for some reason, the input html did not post correctly, and I cannot edit or delete that comment, so I'll try to post it in the order it actually appears:

<input id="username" class="input" type="text" cols="" rows="" size="30" value="" name="username"/>

Comment: Much thanks for the heads up about empty on value rather then on key.  For some reason I had the silly thought that doing a check for an empty key would tell me if its value was empty... Oy.

Thanks again for your help, it's much-appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Running the following code through PHP's interactive commandline just affirms [Tom Haigh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124679/is-there-a-way-to-order-an-associative-array-by-how-the-keys-are-inserted-with-ph/1124685#1124685)'s statement

> It should already be in that order.
>   PHP arrays are sorted so the elements
>   will be in the order in which you
>   inserted them.

```
<?php
$a = array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'class'=>'input',
    'name'=>'username',
    'id'=>'username',
    'value'=>'',
    'size'=>'30',
    'rows'=>'',
    'cols'=>''
);
print_r($a);
/* 
Array
(
    [type] => text
    [class] => input
    [name] => username
    [id] => username
    [value] =>
    [size] => 30
    [rows] =>
    [cols] =>
) 
*/
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . ' => ' . $v . "\n";
}
/* 
type => text
class => input
name => username
id => username
value =>
size => 30
rows =>
cols =>
*/
```

You're sure that this is exactly the code you're using and there is nothing *happening* to `$input_array` between creation and looping?

**EDIT:**

Just a simple and perhaps stupid question: Where do you check how the resulting string in `$input` looks like? If you do so in e.g. FireBug's HTML navigator the attributes' order won't match the real order in the HTML source as FireBug displays the DOM tree generated from the source (and potential Javascript manipulation) which means that it can reorder the attributes at will...

Comment: This firebug issue is precisely the problem I was having.  Only after checking the source did I realize that what Mr. Haigh said was in fact true.  Much thanks!